# How can I make f motions wrap across lines?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, normal-mode

I don't actually want `f` itself to wrap across lines, but I would like to know how I can create a single key mapping which will jump to the next instance of the letter which follows it.

The mapping could be `f` or something else; perhaps I would use `<C-/>` which seems unbound.

The intention is that it would operate sort of like a function, and would take the next letter as its argument and perform:

```
/<argument><CR>
```

Is this possible, or would there have to be a separate key mapping for every letter, e.g.

```
nnoremap <C-/>a /a<CR>
nnoremap <C-/>b /b<CR>
...
```

?

Comment: An easy answer would be to use (yet another) plugin: https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
nnoremap <expr> <c-f> '/' . nr2char(getchar()) . '<cr>'
```

See `:h getchar` and `:h nr2char` for more info.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  I tried typing it in as an `ex` command (i.e. prefixing it with `:` starting from normal mode) but when I then tried `<c-/>` nothing happened.

Comment: Strange. Could you try to use `f` instead of `<c-/>`?

Comment: Just tried it; still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, that's very strange. This works as expected at my end. Did you remember the `<expr>` part?

Comment: And: Could you try to copy the command and put it in your vimrc?

Comment: I tried that too.  :)  I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.4 using Vim 7.3 if that helps.

Comment: I copied and pasted it and it didn't work because of `<C-/>`. But It did work for me when I substituted `<C-/>` for another key (e.g. `<F2>`).

Comment: Same thing for me: it works with `F2` but not `<c-/>`.

Comment: I think there is a problem mapping `<c-/>`. One could perhaps use `<c-v>` to write the actual key code generated by `<c-/>`, but on my keyboard it seems this only returns `/`, and so it seems `<c-/>` is undefined for me. I am not sure if this is the case for everyone else. In the meantime, I propose that one instead uses a different key, e.g. `<c-f>`.

Comment: Maybe you could add it to your answer, something like “If `<C-/>` doesn't work, press `CTRL-V + CTRL-/` instead, or use another key, e.g., `<C-F>`” To make it work I actually followed these steps. Note that `<C-F>` is used for Vim (see [`:h CTRL-F`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#CTRL-F)). [This](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6917/6698) answer provides some guidance regarding how to find a good key sequence.